# Replace particular string at fixed position using sed

Tags: sed

I have a simple text file containing several lines of data where each line has got exactly 26 characters.
E.g.

```
10001340100491938001945591
10001340100491951002049591
10001340100462055002108507
10001340100492124002135591
10001340100492145002156507
10001340100472204002205591
```

Now, I want to replace 12th and 13th character if only these two characters are 49 with characters 58.

I tried it like this:

```
sed 's/^(.{12})49/\58/' data.txt
```

but am getting this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: invalid reference \5 on `s' command's RHS
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The captured group is `\1`, so you want to put the 11 (not 12) characters, then `58`:

```
sed -E 's/^(.{11})49/\158/' data.txt
```

You also need `-E` or `-r` if you don't want to escape square and curly brackets.

With your input, the command changes `49` to `58` in lines 1, 2, 4 and 5.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I am using sed for the first time. So if I don't use -E how will expression look like?

Comment: Thanks, I got it. sed 's/^\(.\{11\}\)49/\158/' data.txt

Comment: @user333422 With my version of `sed` it's `sed 's/^\(.\{11\}\)49/\158/' data.txt`

Answer (score 5):

If you like to try an `awk` solution:

```
awk 'substr($0,12,2)==49 {$0=substr($0,1,11)"58"substr($0,14)}1' file
10001340100581938001945591
10001340100581951002049591
10001340100462055002108507
10001340100582124002135591
10001340100582145002156507
10001340100472204002205591
```

Answer (score 2):

In your expression you are replacing the first 14 characters (if you got it right). But you need to replace 11 plus the two (12th, 13th). More importantly, `sed` is fussy about escaping brackets, so you need backslashes in front of `\(` and `{` etc. Finally - the number of the capture group is `1`. You omitted that number.

Putting it all together, you get

```
sed 's/^\(.\{11\}\)49/\158/'
```

There are flags you can use in `sed` to make the expressions more "regular" (changing the meaning of `(` vs `\(`). What flag that is depends on your platform (version of `sed`), I believe.

Comment: This does not work, even though it looks similar to the one below. Instead of replacing 49 by 58, it is appending 58 after 49 and making the string 28 chars long

Comment: That's because the captured group includes both 11 chars and 49.

Comment: @user333422 - yes I'm sorry there was a transposition of characters. The `49` had to be outside the capture group so it is not repeated during the substitution. I have edited my answer.